# Python Formula Creation

Tags: python

I need to create a formula with the following criteria.  Weight, Quantity, Unit, and Price are all float.

Formula has 4 parameters:  Weight, Quantity, Unit, Price

IF Weight is 0 then `(Quantity * Unit)/Price` 
Then if above result is GT or LT a value return `X`

IF Weight is not 0 then `(Weight * Unit)/Price` 
Then if above result is GT or LT a value return `X`

```
def CatchWeight(totCatchWgt, QtyShip, Unit, Extended):
    try:
        v_calc = 0
        if totCatchWgt == 0:
            v_calc = (QtyShip * Unit)/Extended
            if v_calc < 0.9 or v_calc > 1.111:
                return "X"
        elif (totCatchWgt < 0) | (totCatchWgt > 0):
            v_calc = (totCatchWgt * Unit)/Extended
            if v_calc < 0.9 or v_calc > 1.111:
                return "X"
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
```

Current formula is not examining Weight = 0 correctly and both if statements are returning `X` regardless if weight is 0 or not 0 on same line.

Comment: What are all the parameters and what is the expected/actual result when it is not returning the correct result?

Comment: It looks like the `elif` can simply be `else`.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that includes your desired outcome.

Comment: When do you wants to return the calculated value `v_calc` ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using something like this to have cleaner code and achieve your objective.

```
def check_v_calc(v_calc):
    if v_calc < 0.9 or v_calc > 1.111:
        return "X"
    else:
        # should return some resonable value
        return "Y"

def CatchWeight(totCatchWgt, QtyShip, Unit, Extended):
    if Extended == 0:
        # only case when we will get ZeroDivisionError
        raise ZeroDivisionError('Extended parameter cannnot be zero!')
    if totCatchWgt == 0:
        v_calc = (QtyShip * Unit)/Extended
    else:
        v_calc = (totCatchWgt * Unit)/Extended
    return check_v_calc(v_calc)
```